# MongoDB - should my user document hold a list of project ids?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

I have collections of `users` and `projects`.
Every project is connected exactly to one user.

My question is: should every user hold the list of project ids?

If i want to retrieve all the projects of a specific user, which option is more efficient and best practice:

1. Create an index on projects collection on the user id property. than just query on user id property.
2. Create an index on project collection on the project id property. than, if the user holds its project ids, just query projects collection for those specific ids.

Which option to choose? Maybe there is a third option that is better?
The advantage of the first option, is that i don't need to update the list of project in the user document when deleting/adding projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Every project is connected exactly to one user.

A `user` can have many `projects` (and a project is associated with one user only). This is a **one-to-many** relationship.

> My question is: should every user hold the list of project ids?

Every `user` should store the list of his/her `projects`. For example:

```
user:
    id: <some value>,
    name: <some value>,
    email: <some value>,
    projects: [
        { projectId: <some value>, projectName: <...>, projectDescription: <....>, otherInfo: { fld1: <...>, fld2: <...>, etc. } },
        { projectId: <some value>, projectName: <...>, projectDescription: <....>, otherInfo: { fld1: <...>, fld2: <...>, etc. } },
         ...
    ]
```

Note that each `project` is a sub-document (object or embedded document) within the `projects` array. A `project` has its related details like, `projectId`, `projectName`, etc..

> If i want to retrieve all the projects of a specific user, which
>   option is more efficient and best practice:
>
> a. Create an index on projects collection on the user id property.
>   than just query on user id property.
>
> b. Create an index on project collection on the project id property.
>   than, if the user holds its project ids, just query projects
>   collection for those specific ids.

I think, there should be only **one collection** called as `user_projects`. Assuming that: (i) a `user` may have 0 to 100 projects, and (ii) a `project`'s details are not too huge.

This is a model of embedding the 'many' side of the 1-to-N relationship into the 'one' side. This a recommended way, de-normalizing the data. This has the advantage of efficient and fast queries. This simplifies transactions, as writes (inserts, updates and deletes) are going to be atomic with single operation to a document within the same collection.

> About retrieving all projects for a specific user:

You will be using the `user` `id` or `name` (with a unique index) to retrieve a document,  and it will be very fast query. You can have index on the `projects` array (indexes on array fields are called as **Multikey Indexes**) - on the project's fields. For example, index on `projectId` or/and `projectName` makes sense.

You can get all projects for a user - its a simple query using the `user` `id` / `name`. Query *projection* allows what information related to `project` is displayed. You can use a `find` or `aggregate` method to build the query.
You can query a specific `project` for a `user`, using the `projectId` or `projectName`. Since there are indexes on `user` and `project` fields, this will be an efficient query.

So, my recommendation is to have a single collection, `user_projects`, with a `user`'s information and the `projects` information embedded in it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So your recommendation is always to have one collection? also if I have `Offers` for every project? (One-to-Many) . no referencing at all? the queries are more complicated, and what if i want to search projects by their properties? it will be less efficient query.

Comment: **(1)** _"the queries are more complicated, and what if i want to search projects by their properties? it will be less efficient query"_ : Querying will be easier as it is, and with indexing the queries will be efficient (and fast). One of the main aspects of building a data model, is knowing ahead what the important queries are - you had not mentioned any. But, you are expecting a lot, without mentioning. You are thinking queries are complicated - how? To understand querying you need knowledge of working with arrays in MongoDB data models and the associated methods.

Comment: **(2)** _"...also if I have Offers for every project? (One-to-Many)"_ : Your question didn't reflect any details about it. My answer is based on the information you had made available. I don't know the magnitude of your model. A project can have offers, teams, tracking, billing, and many more (I haven't taken those into consideration either).

Comment: **(3)** _"So your recommendation is always to have one collection?"_ From the given information (in the question post), yes.