# Should I use "pointers" to reference objects in another collection, or store those objects directly (MongoDB)?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, schema

I have two potential collections 1) Accounts and 2) Jobs. The Accounts collection stores "account" documents, which contain info about a user account. Fields include username, email, password, description, etc.

The Jobs collection contains "Job" documents, which contain information about a job, with fields such as: title, description, date created, relevant skills, etc.

Essentially, users can create jobs, and thus these two collections are tied together, since I would like to display the jobs on the user Dashboard UI. I have thought of 3 scenarios to achieve this:

1. Each Job document has a `UserID` field, which acts as a pointer to the corresponding account that created the job. When the dashboard loads, a query is done in the jobs collection for all `UserID` fields matching the accountID.
2. Each Account document has a field `JobIDs`, which is an array of "pointers" that references each of the JobIDs that were created by an account. When the dashboard loads, it loops through this array, performing a query based on the JobID to find the corresponding jobs in the Jobs collection.
3. On each Account document, there is simply a `jobs` field, which is an array of objects, and each object represents a job.

Which is the best implementation and why? I realize for choice 3, there seems to be the benefit of not having to do any queries, but with the downside of potentially huge documents. With the "pointer" implementation, would it be slow to search an entire collection?

Comment: How are you planning to query? What does your research show? There is no "best" unless you define it in enough detail that all would agree an answer. And unfortunately it's chaotically dependent on details. [ask]

Comment: Your modeling should generally depend upon the use case - the important queries in your application. See [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/index.html). Also, see this post: [MongoDB - should my user document hold a list of project ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624246/mongodb-should-my-user-document-hold-a-list-of-project-ids)