# Question about MongoDB data modelling with one-to-many relationship

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, data-modeling

I am designing a course review system and I have Review documents that refer to a review made for a course by a user.

I also have course documents and I am having trouble designing a data model that satisfies my needs.

The relation between course and review is one to many.

I have 2 options:

1. Embed Course in their Review objects which are many:

In this case, course objects do not exist on their own but I have to allow my users to search through courses so in that case, I would need to run a query on Review objects to search for courses.

2. If I store courses in a separate collection and reference through has_many: reviews

I also need to find the reviews for a course when the user clicks on a course after searching and with this design, I will need to run a query when retrieving reviews for a course and also when I am displaying the review, I will need to display course too so I would need to run another query.

What would be the best design in this case? I thought if I could find a way to keep Courses as a separate entity and still embed it inside Reviews as well.

Edit: I have decided to embed reviews inside courses as suggested but I have some new questions now:

For following questions please assume that I have embedded reviews inside course.

1. When inserting reviews, should I do it in ReviewController by finding its course by id and inserting inside its reviews array?
2. When a user searches for a course, I would like to return last 10 reviews with the course information instead of all reviews because it may slow down fetching the search results. How can I achieve this after putting all reviews inside courses as you mentioned?
3. I also have users who enter the reviews (one to many again), I am planning to show recent reviews with usernames, is there a way to embed only username field of user collection inside review?
4. To find a certain users reviews I will need to iterate over all courses, right? It is not a very common query but is there a way to make it faster with an index?

Comment: See this post: [MongoDB - should my user document hold a list of project ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624246/mongodb-should-my-user-document-hold-a-list-of-project-ids/61626365#61626365)

Comment: Thank you, it was a great answer :) I have edited my question by adding my concerns about this new model, please check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modeling suggestions for - *course has reviews and reviews are made by users*.

> I have decided to embed reviews inside courses as suggested but I have
> some new questions now:

> 1. When inserting reviews, should I do it in ReviewController by finding its course by id and inserting inside its reviews array?

You are *updating* a course collection document. The [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) query filter will be by the course id (or name) - and you will `$push` ([$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html) is an update operator) a review sub-document (or embedded document) into the course document's `reviews` *array* field.

The `course` collection document can be like this:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  name: <string>,
  description: <string>,
  reviews: [
     { _id: <some id>, date: <date>, content: <string>, user: <...> },
     { _id: <some id>, date: <date>, content: <string>, user: <...> },
      ...
  ]
}
```

The `reviews` sub-document can have both user's name and id *or* just one of them.

> 2. When a user searches for a course, I would like to return last 10 reviews with the course information instead of all reviews because it
>    may slow down fetching the search results. How can I achieve this
>    after putting all reviews inside courses as you mentioned?

You can make this an Aggregation query. For example,

```
db.course.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: <some course id>  } },    // or, this can be filter by course name field
  { $addFields: {
       latestTenReviews: {
           // use $function aggregation operator to sort the reviews by the date field descending and 
           // limit to first ten array elements
       }
    },
])
```

The `$match` stage can use index defined upon the `_id` (it has by default a unique index) *or* define an index on the course''s `name` field.

> 3. I also have users who enter the reviews (one to many again), I am planning to show recent reviews with usernames, is there a way to
>    embed only username field of user collection inside review?

Yes, you store user information in a review as shown in the previous point (2). You can store only the id *or* name *or* both, depending upon your need. When the reviews are queried for a course, the user names will show, if the names are stored. In case names are not stored, you may have to use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) aggregation stage to make a "join" operation to get the user details, like name.

> 4. To find a certain users reviews I will need to iterate over all courses, right? It is not a very common query but is there a way to
>    make it faster with an index?

You can define an index on the user field of the `reviews` array field's sub-document. Indexes on array fields are called as [Multikey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html). The query with user field as filter criteria will benefit from this index.

Comment: Thank you man, you have made it much more clear for me. I have been struggling for a long time with this :) 

A small final question: do you think which one is better in terms of performance: Fetching 10 reviews along with the course information after search or postponing fetching the reviews to when the user clicks on a course to view its reviews? In the second scenario there will be a TCP overhead and another request is sent so I believe first one will be faster but on the other hand, including reviews may cause search to get slower by sending more data. I would like to hear your opinion

Comment: I suggest you think about functionality of the application rather than the performance - when designing. What will be the functionality? Thats the question you need to ask _yourself_ (or a client if you are working with one). Generally, when you show one selected course, I think you show the recent reviews for that course. But, when you show all courses - you may not show any reviews. They are two different functions - so, different queries.

Comment: No, I am not talking about functionality. I will not show reviews right away, I will show it when the user picks a course but I thought I could fetch the reviews when fetching the course search results on the search screen, store them on Frontend, and show after the user picks a course. The alternative is to fetch the reviews after the user picks a course. If the question is too specific, I can understand :)

Comment: You can try the queries yourself with some data, indexes and run an `explain` on the queries - it will give some insight into the "performance" aspect of the queries. Aspects like, amount of data, indexes, and how you build the query can affect the performance.